# How can I count the values in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, count

I want to get the statistics of a long column, but I have the problems that in the colomn are diffrent datas(**A,B,C,D..**) and the same values (**2**) that I will count.

Example:

```
A
2
2
2
2
B
2
2
C
D
E
2
2
```

Output will be like:

```
A 4
B 2
C
D
E 2
```

Comment: So you want to count the number of 2s that follow each letter?

Comment: Are the items for input in a separate file, exactly as you posted? I'm making a script for you :)

Comment: Yes i want to count the numbers 2.

Comment: The all datas are in the same file. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check where the `Series`, `s`,  equals your magic number. Form groups after masking by that same check, but forward filling.

```
u = s.eq('2')  # `2` if it's not a string
u.groupby(s.mask(u).ffill()).sum()

A    4.0
B    2.0
C    0.0
D    0.0
E    2.0
dtype: float64
```

---

Input data:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(list('A2222B22CDE22'))
```

Comment: Easier on the eyes and clearer to the actual values using `s = pd.Series(list('A2222B22CDE22'))` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that we are working with a text file. ('test_input.txt')

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test_input.txt', header=None)
data = list(data[0])
final_out = dict()
last_item = None

for item in data:
    try:
        item = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        item = str(item)    

    if isinstance(item, str):
        last_item = item
        final_out[last_item] = 0

    if isinstance(item, int):
        final_out[last_item] += 1    

print(final_out)
## {'A': 4, 'B': 2, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 2}

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_out, orient='index'))

##    0
## A  4
## B  2
## C  0
## D  0
## E  2

# For order column, create first.
dataframe = dataframe.rename(columns={0:'unique'})
print(dataframe)

# Ordering
dataframe = dataframe.sort_values(by=['unique'])
print(dataframe)
```

Comment: You can try online on [this link](https://repl.it/@menezesenderson/Question-59090348).

Comment: Do you have some suggestions how can I sort by values? :)

Comment: You can use [sort by method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) of pandas, If you can't make sort, let me know that I update Repl.it online.

Comment: I dont know how to sort print datas. I dont have index, the first I must make indeks and than sortet by index?

Comment: Thank you a lot!